# Avoid using "/index/index" twice in Zend Framework Routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I am new to Zend Framework. I have a page that is:

```
http://localhost/demo/public/index/index/catid/art
```

I want to change that into

```
http://localhost/demo/public/art
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Also, why does it put `index` twice? Even my pagination has it, like:

```
http://localhost/demo/public/index/index/page/2
```

In my opinion is a little bit annoying. I would like the pagination to be

```
http://localhost/demo/public/page/2
```

Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Did you really need to confuse your question by having "/demo/demo/public/" prefixed in every URL? I had to assume that your baseURL started from `/demo/demo/public/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default route works by using:

`/module/controller/action`

So if you have a module called "default", and your controller called "index", and an action called "index", then the most verbose way to refer to that specific action would be:

`/module/controller/action`

In order to set up a route you would use:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
           'page/:page',
           array(
              'module' => 'default'
              'controller' => 'index',
              'action' => 'index'
            ),
            array(
               'page' => '\d+'
             )
          );
```

You could then get the page param in your controller using

`$this->getRequest->getParam("page");`

Comment: it worked like a charm for the pagination. How can I do it for the first example? to hide the parameter?

Comment: You can figure this one out. :) I helped you on the more difficult example. Find  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static